# Python try / except keep trying until no errors

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have the following code that occasionally crashes due to a permissions bug.  I am trying to wrap it up in a `try / except` statement that will keep trying to launch the driver until successful...

```
def init_driver():
    ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile")
    ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
    return driver

driver = init_driver()
```

I have seen examples letting me print a message if an error occurs but how do I get it to keep retrying?  Does anybody have an example they can point me at?

Comment: Btw, where does `driver` get initialised?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it if you don't want to use a loop. Just recall the function on the exception

```
 import sys

 def init_driver(tries=0):

     try:
         ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile");
         ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
         return driver

     except Exception: #This should be the exception you expect and not a catch all
         if tries < sys.getrecursionlimit(): #By default 1,000 can be bumped up by setrecursionlimit
             return init_driver(tries+1)
         #just for kicks
         #else:
             #sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() + 1)
             #print("Yes we'll win this game the old-fashioned way, the tried and true way:")
             #print("We'll cheat!")
             #refactor / prettify if's to call init_driver if you want to cheat.
         else:
             print("OH NO RECURSION LIMIT HIT!!!!!! (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻")

 driver = init_driver()
```

Comment: Need to return `init_driver()` in the except-block

Comment: Lol thank you for adding in the recursion limit conditions.

Comment: Welcome lol. I didn't even think about it until you commented. Thought I'd try to make it differ some from other posts since we're all very self-similar in our answers.

Comment: Also resetting the recursion limit will actually work until you get a...wait for it...stack overflow

Answer (score 13):

Here's a loop that iterates over attempts:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver = init_driver()
        break
    except Foo:
        continue
```

Note that this is not a bare `except` clause.  Bare `except`s are dangerous because they can capture things like `NameError` that are so rarely meant to be caught.  You should put the specific exception you expect to catch here.

Comment: It doesn't really matter for a statement like `break`, but technically you want to `try` only `init_driver()`, and if it succeeds, then you `break`. That is more canonically expressed with `else: break` after the `except` block. Again, not much difference for just `break`, but moving it to the `else` can look more clear (also good practice for when it's something more complex than `break`).

Answer (score 3):

Other answers are fine but they will keep retrying until it hits the recursion depth limit. Consider adding a retry limit:

```
def init_driver(retry_limit=10, nretry=0):
    if nretry >= retry_limit:
       return # retry limit reached, maybe raise an exception?
    try:
        ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile");
        ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
    except SomeException:
        return init_driver(nretry=nretry+1)
    return ffprofile

driver = init_driver()
```

Comment: Technically recursive solutions will stop retrying after it hits the recursion depth limit set by python. By default this is 1,000 so setting a smaller limit not based on maximum recursion depth is probably wise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution (with keeping track of the retries):

```
def init_driver(retries=0):
    try:
        ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile");
        ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
    except:
        print('attempt nr. ' + str(retries))
        return init_driver(retries+1)
    return driver
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
def init_driver():
    driver = None
    ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile");
    ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
    # do something with a valid profile and set driver to something other than None
    return driver

driver = None
while driver is None:
    driver = init_driver()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change required.  Where Foo is the specific exception you get with the permissions bug.

```
def init_driver():
    try:
        ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile");
        ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
        return driver
    except Foo:
        return init_driver()

driver = init_driver()
```